# Unity script preprocessing before compile or load with Roslyn Syntax Rewriter?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, msbuild, roslyn

I'm looking for ways to "rewrite/tweak" C#-scripts in a Unity3d-project somewhere between me editing them in VS and the compilation before running/building the project in the Unity editor. I have seen that Roslyn Source Generators is possible to integrate in Unity, but I much much rather use a Roslyn Syntax Rewriter, if I could only find a way. It does not seem to be possible to integrate syntax rewriters in a normal .NET build in VS (it would have been awesome if it did though) but I was thinking that perhaps Unity have some hooks I could use instead? Perhaps when the script-resources are reloaded after being edited? I don't want to make the changes permanent though, but only visible for the build process. Any other hooks or hacks I could use here? If I only could get the script-text and transform it a little bit before the build... I would be so happy...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for [`IPreprocessBuildWithReport.OnPreprocessBuild`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Build.IPreprocessBuildWithReport.OnPreprocessBuild.html) which allows you to run anything just before a build starts.

Note though that if you modify any files in there it would probably still be permanent.

I think you can easily prevent this from happening by using version control and just reset after building ;)

Alternatively you could of course somehow store your changes (e.g. in copied temporary files) and revert in [`IPostprocessBuildWithReport.OnPostprocessBuild`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Build.IPostprocessBuildWithReport.OnPostprocessBuild.html).

Or if you know what you are doing you could rather modify the precompiled assemblies in [`IIl2CppProcessor.OnBeforeConvertRun`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Build.IIl2CppProcessor.OnBeforeConvertRun.html) which wouldn't affect your c# source code files but rather only the built managed assemblies right before they are transcripted into c++